# JavaFX wait / notify on Javafx thread or nested event loop

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

Is there a way to do a "wait()" on the javafx thread that pauses the execution of a method until a background task finishes but allowing the javafx thread to continue.

I have found a propietary method to do something like this

Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(key);
and 
Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(key, value);

Imagine that you have an @FXML action method when the user clicks a button and inside that method (running on the FX Thread) I want to do the following:

1 get a value from a javafx observable property
2 disable an area of the screen and display a progress indicator
3 call a long running task on a server and stop the excution of the action method here without blocking the UI (or in other words, letting the user navigate to another screen while the background task runs)
4 continue here on the fx thread reenabling the ui and hiding the progress indicator
5 update the UI with values returned from the server.

I know one can use a javafx Task to achieve a similar thing, but that would require moving 4 and 5 to the suceeded() method of the javafx task and that is not what i want.

We've got a framework which allows the developer to annotate some of the remote service stubs on a javafx controller with a @Background annotation and replaces those stubs with a jdk dynamic proxy which switches all invocations to any method in the stubs to run on a non javafx thread and continue on 4 when the server call has finished so we don't have to fill up our code with javafx thread synchronization code.

The Toolkit.getToolkit().enterNestedEventLoop(key); and Toolkit.getToolkit().exitNestedEventLoop(key, value); work well in most cases, except in some scenarios like:

- if the invocation happens on the javafx thread at application startup time (prepopulating a screen with server data on startup)
- if a @FXML action method has two server calls in the same method

Comment: Try http://news.kynosarges.org/2014/05/01/simulating-platform-runandwait/

Comment: Sorry, i just rewrote the question. I can see runAndWait is not what i am looking for. I'll try again:

Comment: Have a look at [this article, by Adam Bien](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javafxinteg-2062777.html), which outlines some strategies for managing services on background threads in JavaFX. He uses the `Task` API, which I strongly recommend you do, but shows some patterns which might help keep your code clean.